# Chain several ssh tunnels

Tags: ssh, rsync, tunnel

I'm new on this forum.

I have the following configuration:

```
my_computer gateway1 gateway2 host_to_reach.
```

I can access gateway1 only with an ssh tunnel which has been created by a server where I have no access (I can only do ssh -p 4022 localhost to access gateway1). I'am then free to create a tunnel to access host_to_reach from gateway1 through gateway2.

My question: Can I access directly host_to_reach from my_computer ? One of the needs behind this is to `rsync` my_computer and host_to_reach.

Thank for help. LM

Comment: You would need to ask the administrator of that server, but I suspect they do that for security.

Answer (score 0):

How do you creating the tunnel to 'host_to_reach' from gateway1 exactly?

If you have the access to gateway1 then you can create a multi-hop SSH tunnel like it shows [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/things-to-do-with-ssh-ssh-tunneling.html).

But I'm not sure exactly that it can be used at your environment.